# I have a problem with misplaced emails

Tags: email

I occasionally find that emails become confused and an email belonging to one person can appear in the thread of another person.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Application? Version? I've seen this in Mail 11.2.

Comment: Yes its version 11.2

Comment: Put the name of the application and its version number in your question. An example would be great too. Not many are going to bother answering if you don't bother asking well.